# Can I specialize a generic function on a type passed as a parameter?

Tags: swift, generics

I want to be able to specialize a generic function by passing a type as an argument, instead of having to declare a variable having the desired type and writing an assignment to that variable.

In my use case, I'm walking up the responder chain looking for an object that conforms to a certain protocol. If found, I'd like to call a method on that object.

I'm trying to do it in a "swift-y" (i.e. type safe) way.

The code I'm currently using looks like this:

```
if let r:UndoManager = self.findResponder() {
    r.undo(...)
}
```

but that makes it hard to chain in a statement.

I want to do something more succinct, like the following, passing the desired protocol as an argument to my function.

```
self.findResponder( UndoManager )?.undo(...)
```

In this example, say I have protocol *UndoManager*, defined as

```
protocol UndoManager {
    func undo(...)
}
```

Also, my declaration of *findResponder()* currently looks like

```
public extension NSReponder {
    public func findResponder<T>() -> T? {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused.  I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish at all.

Comment: On the face of it you can already do what you want to do – if `findResponder()` returns something optional with an `undo()` operation, then you can write `findResponder()?.undo(…)` without resorting to further techniques.

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity That would be ideal, but it produces "Could not find member 'undo'".

Comment: This does work however: `(findResponder() as Undo?)?.undo(...)`... which is only slightly longer

Comment: You probably need to edit your question to post a minimal working bit of code as it isn’t clear from your samples what’s causing the problem.

Comment: My first code snippet works. It's what I'm using currently. This is a question about shortening my syntax. I'd like to be able to pass a type as an argument to a function and have it be specialized on that.

Comment: I think the answer to my question is "you can't do what you want" but I'm hoping someone on SO will confirm one way or the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do `self.findResponder( UndoManager )?.undo(...)` instead of `(findResponder() as Undo?)?.undo(...)`, the method signature would be:

```
    public func findResponder<T>(_: T.Type) -> T? {
        // ...
    }
```